# Bahmni file upload issue

Tags: docker, openmrs

I have tried installing bahmni docker from this link: https://bahmni.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BAH/pages/3117744129/Getting+Started+Quickly+with+Bahmni+on+Docker#Running-Bahmni-Standard.
Everything is running fine but when I try to upload document, it appears as a broken image[image]

When I check the patient-document container log, it shows permission denied. How do I fix this?

I tried changing permission of the folder by going inside the container. I did chmod 777 to document_uploads folder and now I can see images that I have saved appear, however, when I try to upload new image again, it changes permission to rwr and does on appear on UI.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the issue discussed in [Openmrs Talk](https://talk.openmrs.org/t/getting-ngnix-404-error-for-uploaded-files-in-csv-import-admin-module-in-bahmni-docker/41561).

Bahmni product has resolved this issue, and we appreciate you bringing it to our attention. The card tracking this fix is located at [BAH-3528](https://bahmni.atlassian.net/browse/BAH-3528).

By pulling the latest image, you can obtain the fix.

Comment: can you add an image ID for future reference?